# isinstance - Python Class

Tags: python

I have a number of classes that I am passing around my code as objects prior to instantiating them. I'm trying to test the type of the class in a similar way to testing the type of an object instance to workout which one to use. I should mention these classes can be subclasses of each other.

Unfortunately, using `isinstance(MyClass, MyClass)` in this manner on the class itself returns False. According to the docs class objects are of type `type`.

So my question is - Is it possible for me to workout the class type in the same way you can with instance types? How would I go about this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Use [duck typing](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/duck_typing.shtml).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?

If you want to know whether class `A` is a subclass of a class `B` you could just use `issubclass`:

```
issubclass(A, B)
```

For your particular case, you could just do `Myclass == MyClass` or even `MyClass is MyClass`.

In general, deep introspection is not such a good idea, and is usually left for generic frameworks like Django.